# The Google Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from Google's servers

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps-api-3, proxy

I use Google maps js API but without directly asking for it ( cause of proxy limitations). So until now I had a php script (in my server) as a middle layer. So I had this line in my index.html:
`<script src="https://my-production-domain/google.php"></script>`

Everything worked perfect, until now. I get this response from API:

> The Google Maps JavaScript API must be downloaded directly from Google's servers

Is there any workaround this issue? Its not possible for me to change proxy rules.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not believe there is a way around this.

Comment: That is probably against the terms of use (downloading the API and storing the javascript files on your server).

Comment: In my case empty cache and hard reload of browser helped.